# Haskell: Can a function be compiled?

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc, hint, ghc-api

Consider a simple Haskell [Brainf*ck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter. Just look at the `interpret` function.

```
import Prelude hiding (Either(..))
import Control.Monad
import Data.Char (ord, chr)

-- function in question
interpret :: String -> IO ()
interpret strprog = let (prog, []) = parse strprog
                    in execBF prog


interpretFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
interpretFile fp = readFile fp >>= interpret


type BF = [BFInstr]
data BFInstr = Left | Right | Inc | Dec | Input | Output | Loop BF

type Tape = ([Integer], [Integer])

emptyTape = (repeat 0, repeat 0)

execBFTape :: Tape -> BF -> IO Tape
execBFTape = foldM doBF

execBF :: BF -> IO ()
execBF prog = do
  execBFTape emptyTape prog
  return ()

doBF :: Tape -> BFInstr -> IO Tape
doBF ((x:lefts),   rights)   Left     = return (lefts,         x:rights)
doBF (lefts,    (x:rights))  Right    = return (x:lefts,         rights)
doBF (left,     (x:rights))  Inc      = return (left,      (x+1):rights)
doBF (left,     (x:rights))  Dec      = return (left,      (x-1):rights)
doBF (left,     (_:rights))  Input    = getChar >>= \c -> return (left, fromIntegral (ord c):rights)
doBF t@(_,      (x:     _))  Output   = putChar (chr (fromIntegral x)) >> return t
doBF t@(left,   (x:     _)) (Loop bf) = if x == 0
                                        then return t
                                        else do t' <- execBFTape t bf
                                                doBF t' (Loop bf)

simpleCommands = [('<', Left),
                  ('>', Right),
                  (',', Input),
                  ('.', Output),
                  ('+', Inc),
                  ('-', Dec)]

parse :: String -> (BF, String)
parse []          = ([], [])
parse (char:prog) = case lookup char simpleCommands of
                      Just command -> let (rest, prog') = parse prog
                                      in (command : rest, prog')
                      Nothing      ->
                        case char of
                          ']' -> ([], prog)
                          '[' -> let (loop, prog')  = parse prog
                                     (rest, prog'') = parse prog'
                                 in (Loop loop:rest, prog'')
                          _   -> parse prog
```

So I have a function applied like `interpret "[->+<]"`. This gives me an `IO ()` monadic action which executes the given program. It has the right type to be a `main` of some program.

Let's say I would like to have this action compiled to an executable, that is, I would like to generate an executable file with the result of `interpret ...` to be the main function. Of course, this executable would have to contain the GHC runtime system (for infinite lists, integer arithmetic etc.).

Questions:

1. It is my opinion that it is not possible at all to just take the monadic action and save it to be a new file. Is this true?
2. How could one go about reaching a comparable solution? Do the GHC Api and [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hint) help?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I oversimplified in the original question. Of course, I can just write a file like this:

```
main = interpret "..."
```

But this is not what we usually do when we try to compile something, so consider `interpretFile :: FilePath -> IO ()` instead. Let the BF program be saved in a file (`helloworld.bf`).

How would I go about creating an executable which executes the contents of `helloworld.bf` without actually needing the file?

```
$ ./MyBfCompiler helloworld.bf -o helloworld
```

Comment: For efficiency, I suppose?

Comment: You appear to be asking for a way to write a compiler. I hope you understand that this is *quite* difficult. Do you mean to find a way to use GHC to compile your `.bf` files?

Comment: Saving the IO action, if it were possible, would essentially reduce to saving the BF source code along with the interpreter. This would result into a quite trivial compiler (at least without a serious partial evaluator, which is not available at the moment, AFAIK). Since the interpreter part is fixed, it looks much simpler to save only the source code -- essentially avoiding the compilation step. If you want  real compilation you probably need to write a real compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is basically no.

There are many ways to construct `IO` values:

1. Built in functions like `putStrLn`
2. Monad operations like `return` or `>>=`

Once you have an IO value there are three ways to break it down:

1. Set `main` equal to the value
2. `unsafePerformIO`
3. As the return value of an exported C function

All of these break down into converting an `IO a` into an `a`. There is no other way to inspect it to see what it does.

Similarly the only thing you can do with functions is put them in variables or call them (or convert them to C function pointers).

There is no sane way to otherwise inspect a function.

One thing you could do which isn’t compiling but is linking is to have your interpreter main function run on some external c string, build that into a static object, and then your “compiler” could make a new object with this C string of the program in it and link that to what you already have.

---

There is this theory of partial evaluation that says that if you do partial evaluation of a partial evaluator applied to an interpreter applied to some input then what you get is a compiler but ghc is not a sufficiently advanced partial evaluator.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure whether you’re asking how you write a compiler that can take as its input a file such as `helloworld.bf`, or how you compile a Haskell program that runs `helloworld.bf`.

In the former case, you would want something a little more fleshed out than this:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_:fileName:_) <- getArgs
  source <- readFile fileName
  interpret source

interpret :: String -> IO ()
interpret = undefined -- You can fill in this piddly little detail yourself.
```

If you want the latter, there are a few different options.  First, you can store the contents of your `*.bf` file in a string constant (or bettter yet, a `Text` or strict `ByteString`), and pass that to your interpreter function.  I’d be surprised if GHC is optimistic enough to fully inline and expand that call at compile time, but in principle a Haskell compiler could.

The second is to turn Brainfuck into a domain-specific language with operators you define, so that you can actually write something like

```
interpret [^<,^+,^>,^.]
```

If you define `(^<)` and the other operators, the Brainfuck commands will compile to bytecode representing the Brainfuck program.

In this case, there isn’t an obvious benefit over the first approach, but with a more structured language, you can do an optimization pass, compile the source to stack-based bytecode more suitable for an interpreter to execute, or generate a more complex AST.

You might also express this idea as

```
interpret
  (^< ^+ ^> ^.)
  input
```

Here, if the Brainfuck commands are higher-order functions with right-to-left precedence, and `interpret bf input = (bf begin) input`, the Brainfuck code would simply compile to a function that the interpreter calls.  This has the best chance of being turned into fast native code.

### Previous Answer

In certain cases, a compiler can inline a function call (there are pragmas in GHC to tell it to do this).  The compiler is also more likely to do what you want if you name the closure, such as:

```
main = interpret foo
```

In GHC, you can give the compiler a hint by adding

```
{-# INLINE main #-}
```

or even

```
{-# INLINE interpret #-}
```

You can check what code GHC generated by compiling the module with `-S` and looking through the source.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized that I oversimplified my question because this answers correctly, but is not what I wanted. Please see the edit.

Comment: @firefrorefiddle Is this one more what you had in mind?